# How to select a sensible tolerance when making approximations in MATLAB

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, matlab, pi

I'm approximating $\pi$ using a series in MATLAB. I can approximate to within a relative error of $3\times 10^{-10}$ of MATLAB's built-in value. How would I choose a sensible tolerance for my approximation? Would it possibly relate to machine epsilon?

Comment: Which series? ${}$

Comment: $ 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + ...$

Comment: Yeow, that one's quite slow to converge. Do you really need to use that series?

Comment: I'm afraid I do. I want to compare it to Matlab's built-in value for pi for a varying number of terms in this series.

Comment: The usual criterion is to stop when the $k$-th term is less than the current partial sum times `eps`.

Comment: Hmm, change that to "absolute value of the $k$-th term"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The usual criterion is to stop when the absolute value of the k-th term is less than the current partial sum times eps"

Thanks to @J.M.